# I have exposed my sin

Tags: sin, tawba, forgiveness

I am a 17 year old Muslim female and I have exposed a sin I commited to many of my friends. At the time, I revealed it because I wanted advice but I did not know that revealing my sins to others is a bad thing. It’s been a long time since I commited that sin and I have made tawbah and I have changed myself.

Will Allah still forgive me?
What should I do next?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Note that "What should I do.." questions attract opinion-based answers and are rather off-topic as we are no peer support.