# Concealing sins pls helppp

Tags: sin

I commited a sin and at the time I told many people about it not knowing that telling others of your sins is a sin. Now that I realize I repent to Allah everyday and I cry and I regret my actions very much. Is there still hope for me? I stopped telling people about the sin I have commited and I will never go near the sin I have commited. Pls answer I need hope

Comment: "Is there still hope for me?" Doubting that there is hope for you would be Kufr (disbelief). God is completely Merciful. If you ask forgiveness sincerely you will, if God wills, be forgiven.

Comment: Re-posting a question is discouraged on this site (https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/52001/13438) we have already linked an answer this is a Q&A site not a typical internet forum.

Answer (score 0):

Of Course, there's a lot of hope for you. Allah loves when someone repents to Allah as :

**Allah (subhana wa ta’ala) loves it when people ask Him to forgive their sins. He is overjoyed with their repentance, since He hates to punish anybody. At the slightest excuse He washes people’s sins away. The only condition is that the human being must truly regret in his/her heart that they did what they did. The sinner should be ashamed of their misdeeds, and discontinue committing such sins. If the resolve to avoid the sin is not there then one has not actually repented.
[Tirmidhi]**

What if someone committed unlimited sins? Our beloved Prophet محمد صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم said:

**“Allah, Blessed and Exalted is He, says, ‘O son of Adam, as long as you call on Me, I shall forgive you of what you have done, and think nothing of it. O son of Adam, even if your sins were to reach up to the clouds in the sky, and then you were to ask for My forgiveness, I would forgive you and think nothing of it. O son of Adam, even if you were to come to Me with sins nearly as great as the earth, and then you were to meet Me after death, not worshipping anything besides Me, I would bring you forgiveness nearly as great as the earth.’” [Tirmidhi]**

Finally, if someone committed sins repent to Allah as Allah didn't set the limit of repentance. Allah accepts hundreds or thousands time repentance of human being. You just repent to Allah with true heart and with true feelings of repentance.